# looping through locally registered components in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component that imports and registers other components locally. I want to loop through components object and render them dynamically. I'm trying to achieve this like the following (inside .vue file):

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="component in components" class="component">
    <component v-bind:is="component"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CarouselDefault from './carousel/CarouselDefault'
import AlertError from './alerts/AlertError'
import AlertInfo from './alerts/AlertInfo'
import AlertSuccess from './alerts/AlertSuccess'
import AlertWarning from './alerts/AlertWarning'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    CarouselDefault,
    AlertError,
    AlertInfo,
    AlertSuccess,
    AlertWarning
  }
}
</script>
```

and I get this error message:

> Property or method "components" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The components property aren't avalibale in template builder of vue, you have to defien a computed or a property of data . 
example:

```
computed:{
components(){
       return [
          CarouselDefault,
          AlertError,
          AlertInfo,
          AlertSuccess,
          AlertWarning
       ];
}
}
```

or

```
data(){
return {
 components:[
    CarouselDefault,
    AlertError,
    AlertInfo,
    AlertSuccess,
    AlertWarning
  ]
}
}
```